# Этимология слова «тельняшка»

Tags: этимология, история

От какого (каких) слова (слов) произошло существительное «тельняшка» (тельняжка)? Существовала ли когда-нибудь «тельняха» (тельняга)?

Comment: И есть ли связь с нательным бельем?

Answer (score 2):

Написание (и проговаривание) *тельняжка, тельняха, тельняга* нормативными не являются, но вполне могут жить в языке: грамматика не нарушена, все три суффикса широко употребляются.

Этимология  ТЕЛЬНЯШКИ как раз затруднений не вызывает (проблемы начнутся с полосками, их числом, их цветами и правом на ношение).

По [Фасмеру](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0),

> тельный ‘носимый непосредственно на теле’ + -яшк(а), от тело, восходит
>   к праслав. *tělo, от кот. в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. тѣло
>   (род. п. тѣлесе), тѣлесьнъ, прил., ст.-слав. тѣло (род. п. тѣлесе,
>   др.-греч. σῶμα).

Или [другой источник](https://krylov.lexicography.online/%D1%82/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0):

> Тельня́шка. Название этого морского нижнего белья образовано от
>   существительного тело. Буквально — «то, что надевают на тело».

В официальном документе  о тельняшке говорилось: «Рубаха, вязанная из шерсти пополам с бумагою», то есть хлопком. Это позволяло проветривать тело при жаре и согревать его во время холодов. Моряки во время дальних странствий порой сами крючком и спицами вязали себе полюбившуюся одежду — это занимало досуг и очень успокаивало нервы.

[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0) даёт подробный отчёт обо всём - за исключением этимологии, и без того прозрачной:

> Тельня́шка (просторечное тельник) — вязаная нательная рубашка,
>   изготовленная из трикотажного полотна и имеющая окраску в виде
>   чередующихся горизонтальных синих (как варианты - темно-зеленых,
>   краповых, васильковых, оранжевых, черных, голубых) и белых полос.
>
> Практическое предназначение полос тельника состояло в том, чтобы
>   сделать человека хорошо заметным на фоне белых парусов, а также
>   облегчить поиск моряка, оказавшегося за бортом.

И ещё много интересного из истории тельняшки собрано в той же википедийной статье - достаточно кликнуть по ссылке.

Но есть и по-другому рассказанное, специалистами:

> ...Интересно само происхождение тельняшки, почему ее так назвали и
>   почему она полосатая. В 60-е годы 19 века наши корабли активно ходили
>   в регион Средиземного моря, в таких городах, как Брест или Мальта, они
>   видели такую полосатую одежду. Она производила очень сильное
>   впечатление, была модной. Если в западной культуре полосатая одежда
>   воспринималась больше как проявление чего-то дьявольского, то в нашей
>   культуре – просто как красивая одежда, подчеркивающая бравый вид
>   военных моряков. И когда экипаж фрегата "Генерал Адмирал", вернувшись
>   из очередного похода, был представлен великому князю Константину
>   Николаевичу, все моряки стояли в этих полосатых рубахах. Великий князь
>   поинтересовался, что это такое, и ему доложили. А доктора дали свое
>   обоснование, что рубашки защищают матроса от простуды. И великий князь
>   учредил эту тельняшку указ от 19 августа старого стиля 1874 года. В
>   соответствии с этим указом тельняшка была положена всем нижним чинам
>   нашего флота.
>
> Этот полосатый предмет одежды очень любила Шанель, сама ее очень
>   активно носила. На самом деле, это можно объяснить ее любовью к
>   морскому стилю, потому что и первый свой магазин она открыла в Довиле,
>   и довольно много времени проводила на морских курортах. В 20-е годы,
>   когда ее карьера была в самом расцвете, очень многие богатые люди
>   устремлялись как раз на побережье, поскольку это было модное
>   времяпрепровождение. Тогда в моду входят купания, загорелое тело,
>   спортивный образ жизни. Тельняшка в этом смысле некий знак и символ
>   этой эпохи. Тем не менее, это не означает, что полосатая одежда и
>   полоска не присутствовали в моде до тех пор. Судьба полосок в
>   европейской культуре была драматичной, они имели скандальную
>   репутацию. Например, в средние века полоски считались дьявольской
>   материей. Возможно, это связано с тем, что глаз человека в те времена
>   был склонен к тому, чтобы последовательно вычитывать пласт за пластом,
>   и ему было неприятно, если изображение на плоскости было недостаточно
>   отделено от фона. В какой-то момент даже вышел запрет на ношение
>   полосатых тканей.
>
> ---
>
> – Автор книги "Про тельняшку" – морской офицер Олег Шеблыкин считает
>   дьявольское содержание, которое вкладывали в полосатую одежду,
>   принадлежностью западной цивилизации. А в России якобы это всегда
>   воспринималось по-другому. Так ли это?
>
> – Россия, хоть она и идет своим путем, но не настолько уж сильно
>   отделена от этой самой западной цивилизации, эти идеи и в Россию тоже
>   проникали. Пограничная роль полосок сохранилась, скажем, в одежде
>   арестантов, и в России в том числе. В России все системы, призванные
>   сигнализировать об опасности, тоже все полосатые: "зебра", знаки
>   дорожного движения. В этом смысле мы не придумываем ничего нового.
>
> – Вы говорите о том, что полосатая одежда и полоса вообще в культуре
>   моды – это, в первую очередь, сигнал опасности, сигнал границы.
>   Получается, что бело-голубая полоска не несла никакого романтического,
>   не была символом мужественности?

Ответ на последний вопрос и многое другое - см. [источник](https://www.svoboda.org/a/2339225.html).

---

Забавное, но и просветительное:

[Бог шельму метит](https://pikabu.ru/story/proiskhozhdenie_vyirazheniy_kotoryie_myi_upotreblyaem_kazhdyiy_den__71631)

> Слово «шельма» — это искажённое «тельник», или просто «тельняшка». Но
>   почему тельняшку метит на чёрные и белые полосы именно Бог?

[Словарь Шанского](https://etymological.academic.ru/6117/%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0) опровергает искажение тельника:

ШЕЛЬМА

> Заим. в начале XVIII в. через посредство польск. яз. из нем. где
>   Schelm «плут» < «злодей» восходит к др.-в.-нем. scelmo — «смерть» того
>   же корня (*(s)kel-), что и колоть. Шельма буквально «достойный
>   смерти».
>
> Оказывается, раньше священники носили под рясой... именно тельняшки.
>   Так как они были и остаются самым удобным рабочим бельём. От этого
>   русского обычая — носить тельняшку под рясой — и пошло выражение «Бог
>   шельму метит».
>
> ---

[МАЙКА МЕРТВЕЦА](http://oursociety.ru/publ/istorija_veshhej_i_javlenij/istorija_telnjashki/13-1-0-64)

> ...Моряки — самые суеверные люди в мире. И вот одно из главных морских
>   поверий связано с темными и светлыми полосами, нанесенными на
>   тельняшку.
>
> Каждый настоящий моряк уверен, что пучину населяют различные демоны да
>   русалки, и каждый из них представляет собой серьезную опасность для
>   покорителей морей и океанов. Чтобы их обмануть и использовали
>   тельняшку: считалось, что, надев подобную рубаху, моряки казались
>   духам моря уже покойниками, от которых остались только скелеты.
>
> Первыми робу с черно-белыми полосками надели рыбаки французской
>   Бретани, чтобы уберечься от духов моря. В начале XVII века это
>   суеверие распространилось по всему Старому Свету.
>
> Начиная с 1852 года, по французскому стандарту тельняшка обязана была
>   иметь 21 полосу — по числу крупных побед Наполеона. В свою очередь,
>   голландцы и англичане предпочитали тельняшку исключительно с 12
>   поперечными полосами — по количеству ребер у человека.
>
> Если же говорить серьезно, то появление на море тельняшки было
>   продиктовано суровыми обстоятельствами морских путешествий и очень
>   странно, что она не появилась раньше XVII века. Не желая черпать
>   информацию из сомнительных источников, автор статьи обратился к
>   знакомому контр-адмиралу с просьбой рассказать о том, откуда на самом
>   деле появилась эта полосатая рубаха. Адмирал рассмеялся и сказал: «Нам
>   еще в училище преподаватели говорили: полоски на тельняшке — чтобы
>   сачков на фоне парусов видеть».
>
> ---

[История тельняшки с XVI века](https://rus-promisel.ru/istoriya-promyslov/istoriya-telnyashki.html)

---

И маленькая деталь - отдельно:

[Морская тельняшка](http://oursociety.ru/publ/istorija_veshhej_i_javlenij/istorija_telnjashki/13-1-0-64)

> У первой российской тельняшки расстояние между синими полосами
>   составляло примерно 4,5 см. Считалось, что сине-белая гамма тельняшки
>   повторяет цвета Андреевского флага. Белые полосы оказались значительно
>   шире синих. Равноправие между ними было установлено лишь в 1912 году.
>   С этого момента ширина полос составила четверть вершка, в современной
>   мере исчисления примерно 1 см. В качестве материала теперь стали
>   использовать исключительно хлопок.
>
> Повседневной полосатая рубаха стала далеко не сразу. Первое время она
>   предназначалась исключительно для дальних походов. В обычном режиме
>   нижние чины могли надевать ее лишь по воскресеньям, в дни
>   государственных праздников, а также при увольнении на берег. Таким
>   образом, тельняшка из удобного бытового предмета на некоторое время
>   превратилась в элемент парадной формы. Но моряки все равно старались
>   носить ее повседневно, ласково называя «морской душой».

Answer (score 1):

1) В России существует неофициальный праздник —   **День рождения русской тельняшки,** который отмечается **19 августа.** Есть сведения, что в этот день в 1874 году император Александр ІІ подписал указ о введении новой формы, которым тельняшка (специальная «нательная» рубаха) была введена как часть обязательной формы одежды русского моряка. https://fishki.net/2047223-istorija-telnjashki.html

2) А вот слово ***тельняшка*** когда появилось? Назывались ли так обычные (не морские) рубахи?

Схема возможного словообразования: **тело — тельный — тельн/ик, тельн/як, тельн/яшка.**

Примеры: круглый — кругляк, медный — медяк/медяшка.

**В Большом этимологическом словаре** (сост. Климова М.В., 2013 год, 20000 слов) такая запись:

**ТЕЛЬНЯШКА**. Возникновение XIV век, от собственно русского ***тыльный*** от ***тѣло***.

Почему ***тыльный*** — неясно, но интересно, **что XIV век**.

Там же: **РУБАХА** — XIV-XVII век от собственно русского **руб** (плохая одежда) от рубить.

Производное **рубашка** отмечено в тексте 1579 г. (Черных).

3) **Информация из Сети:**

Считается, что первыми робу с черно-белыми полосками надели рыбаки французской Бретани, чтобы уберечься от духов моря. В начале XVII века это суеверие распространилось по всему Старому Свету.

Сегодня уже сложно сказать, **когда русские моряки впервые увидели полосатые рубахи** на своих иностранных коллегах. Скорее всего, это знакомство произошло **в XVII веке в Архангельске,** во время посещения порта английскими или голландскими торговыми судами.

Удивительно, **почему Петр I,** практически целиком перенявший морские традиции Голландии, **сразу не позаимствовал и тельняшку.**

Comment: "Тыльный" - это ошибка конвертации (или при конвертации?). Тѣльный, конечно.

Answer (score 1):

После столь подробных ответов мне нечего добавить по поводу этимологии и словообразования, кроме подтверждения из [МАС](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-academ-term-69381.htm):
ТЕЛЬНЫЙ -ая, -ое. *Разг*
1. Надеваемый прямо на тело; нательный.
*Костюм наших новых знакомых состоял из короткой **тельной рубашки** белого цвета и одного или двух пестрых халатов длиною до колен* (Арсеньев. В горах Сихотэ-Алиня).

И привести примеры использования.

*Смотри-ка — будёновка. Видишь — **тельняха.**

Такая, наверно, у деда была.

Шкатулки под Палех — как урночки с прахом,

как будто Россия уже умерла.*
[Т. Фоминова. Арбат](https://45parallel.net/tatyana_fominova/bessonnitsa/)

*Зелёный чайник на бочонке,

**Тельняга** сохнет на бечёвке,

Вот тут и будет мне постой:

Устал — а мотобот пустой.*
[Д. Сухарев. Сон](http://www.bards.ru/archives/part.php?id=49667)

*Вмиг полосат я, вновь моряк.

Оставлен верный лишь **тельняк**,

А тот японский лапсердак

В музей пошёл, со звуком шмяк.*
В. Поспелов. Океан чувств

Answer (score 0):

Не располагаю сейчас временем на сбор доказательств, но вообще-то любой моряк (а теперь и десантник) знает, что "тельняшка" - слово, которым сухопутные невежи обозвали благородный морской **тельник**.

Естественно, при таком раскладе существование "тельняги" (или чего-то подобного) маловероятно.
Ну а сам "тельник" образован по обычной модели ель-ельник, мельница-мельник, тело-тельник, тут уж совсем не приходится ожидать чего-то экзотического.